# How to make {controller}/{id}/{action} work in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've tried everything but looks like I'm just not getting it at all. My WebApiConfig.cs looks like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "Default",
    "api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "AccountVerification",
    "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    null,
    new { controller = "Account" });
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController {
    public HttpResponseMessage GetByKey(Guid accountID) {
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Verify")]
    public HttpResponseMessage VerifyAccount(Guid accountID) {
        ...
    }
}
```

These methods should get a hit with the following URLs:

```
GET /api/account                                        - WORKS
GET /api/account/00000000-0000-0000-000000000001        - WORKS
GET /api/account/00000000-0000-0000-000000000001/verify - DOESNT WORK
```

I've tried a lot of things; I am definitely doing something wrong here...please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want to test with fake Guids, as well as having optional Guid parameters, they must be Nullable parameters (fake guids will be deserialized as null) :

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage GetByKey(Guid? accountID)
    {
        throw new Exception("GetByKey " + (accountID.HasValue ? accountID.ToString() : "NULL"));
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.ActionName("Verify")]
    public HttpResponseMessage VerifyAccount(Guid? accountID)
    {
        throw new Exception("VerifyAccount "+(accountID.HasValue?accountID.ToString():"NULL"));
    }
}
```

then, your mapping should :

- use the most specific route first
- use the correct parameters names
- use the correct defaults for actions

  ```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      "AccountVerification",
      "api/{controller}/{accountID}/{action}"
      );


  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      "Default",
      "api/{controller}/{accountID}",
      defaults: new { Controller="Account", action = "GetByKey", accountID = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
  ```

Comment: I'll give it a try tonight. Question - isnt a fake guid still a guid; i mean why would it deserialize to null and moreover, my requirement is that accountID parameter of VerifyAccount method must be provided...it's not optional, and, {action} must be "verify" to get resolved to VerifyAccount method...there's no other actions so far in the application

Answer (score 1):

GET /api/account/00000000-0000-0000-000000000001/verify is matching the first route in your routing collection. Therefore, it never inspects the second route to see if it matches. Make "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}" the first route in your collection and it should work correctly.

Comment: Okay I did but its still the same message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'api/account/f476397e-5e3e-470b-8621-573d63698cd7/verify"

Comment: Looks like you have 'v1' between api and the controller action. You need to either remove that or add it to your route definition - "api/v1/{controller}/{id}/{action}".