# Redirect To Action method not mapping correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm calling `RedirectToAction` but it isn't working properly.

I want the resulting URL to look like this:

```
https://localhost:44301/ManageSpaces/123/overview
```

but it looks like this and is missing the action portion of the URL:

```
https://localhost:44301/ManageSpaces/123
```

Here is my `RedirectToAction` call.

```
return RedirectToAction("overview", new RouteValueDictionary(
                new {controller = "ManageSpaces", action = "overview", id = 123}));
```

Here is what my route looks like in `RouteConfig`:

```
 routes.MapRoute("ManageSpaces",
            "ManageSpaces/{id}/{action}",
            new { controller = "ManageSpaces", action = "overview"},
            new { id = @"\d+" } //The regular expression \d+ matches one or more integers
            );
```

Comment: don't know much about asp.net mvc, but shouldn't your default be `new { controller = "ManageSpaces", action = "overview", id = @"\d+"}` PS: Why do you need regex for an id? that's usually simple integers. If you want to make it optional, you can always do `id = UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331050/how-to-make-controller-id-action-work-in-mvc4

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is taking the default route. Rename, remove, or comment out the default route to see if that has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have made your `action` route value optional by providing a default value. Optional values are ignored when resolving the URL.

```
 routes.MapRoute("ManageSpaces",
        "ManageSpaces/{id}/{action}",
        new { controller = "ManageSpaces", action = "overview"},
        new { id = @"\d+" } //The regular expression \d+ matches one or more integers
        );
```

If you want to include the `action` in the URL, you have to make it a required argument.

```
 routes.MapRoute("ManageSpaces",
        "ManageSpaces/{id}/{action}",
        new { controller = "ManageSpaces"},
        new { id = @"\d+" } //The regular expression \d+ matches one or more integers
        );
```